# Как изменить структуру json c помощью C#?

Tags: c#, json

Я получаю json в ответ на запрос. Он выглядит примерно так:
https://pastebin.com/pjdxZunJ

Мне нужно поменять, чтобы получилось так:
https://pastebin.com/Xzjvd1vS

(Нужно убрать

```
"data": {
```

и вместо него добавить

```
"roamingSetttingsVersion": 7,
```

А также внизу убрать

```
  "modified": 1634716353754,
  "type": "Ares.PlayerSettings"
```

)
Данные внутри могут отличаться

Comment: Создайте свою структуру классов, перегоните туда нужные данные и сериализуйте обратно в JSON...

Comment: с помощью библиотеки `JSON.NET` и `JToken` можно удалять, менять, изменять и проводить другие действия с `json`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Данные внутри могут отличаться...

Comment: @KuzCode Можете показать пример? Буду благодарен

Comment: Как только ссылки перестанут работать, ваш вопрос превратится в тыкву и станет бесполезен для StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи достаточно просто будет использовать `JObject` из библиотеки [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\source.json"); // Здесь чтение файла из диска - для примера

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jObjectCorrected = jObject["data"];
jObjectCorrected["roamingSetttingsVersion"] = 7;

var outJson = jObjectCorrected.ToString();
```

---

> Я получаю { "actionMappings": [ { "alt": false, "bindIndex": 0,
> roamingSetttingsVersion нет

`roamingSetttingsVersion`-поле присутствует в `outJson`, просто добавилось оно в середину. JSON формат предполагает то, что порядок полей json-объекта не имеет никакого значения.

---

> А как убрать "modified": 1634716353754, "type": "Ares.PlayerSettings"?

Эти поля удалились из json. Как это произошло? Очень просто. Строка кода:

```
var jObjectCorrected = jObject["data"];
```

вернет "потроха" поля `"data"`, а именно, тот json-объект, который объявлен после `"data":`. Другими словами, мы спустились на один уровень вложенности ниже. Поля `"modified": 1634716353754, "type": "Ares.PlayerSettings"` находятся снаружи по отношению к "потрохам" поля `"data"`, из-за чего они и не вошли в итоговый json-объект

Comment: Я получаю
{
  "actionMappings": [
    {
      "alt": false,
      "bindIndex": 0,

roamingSetttingsVersion нет

Comment: @Viannedi Есть. Он просто в середину попал. Через поиск найдёте. Для json порядок полей не имеет никакого значения

Comment: А как убрать 
  "modified": 1634716353754,
  "type": "Ares.PlayerSettings"

Comment: @Viannedi а их и нет в `outJson` ;)